# No value of FormArray inside a Formgroup

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form defined like this:

```
this.entityForm = this.fb.group({
        // Searching ID
        search: this.fb.group({
            procedures: '',
            areas: '',
            entities: '',
            versions: '',
        }),
        // Entity
        entity: this.fb.group({
            // Id
            name: '',
            version: '',
            // Data Source
            cobolFileName: '',
            cobolUri: '',
            hostDbUri: '',
            hostDbTable: '',    // Format (schema.table)
            wsUri: '',
            // Historice
            historicizeStrategy: '',
            pwx: '',
            // Rows
            rows: this.fb.array([this.newRow()])
        })
    });
```

When i do:

```
let a = this.entityForm.get('entity');
    let b = this.entityForm.get('entity.rows');
    console.log(a.value);
    console.log(b.value);
```

the answer is :

```
{
cobolFileName: "NAME OF FILE"
cobolUri: "mainframe"
historicizeStrategy: "START_END_VALIDITY"
hostDbTable: null
hostDbUri: null
name: "GRZ_PERS"
pwx: false
rows: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
version: 1
wsUri: null
__proto__: Object
}

{
    0: {name: "Column_2", datatype: "INTEGER", defaultValue: "", key: false, masked: true, …}
    1: {name: "Column_1", datatype: "INTEGER", defaultValue: "", key: false, masked: true, …}
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array(0)
}
```

I want to send a.value to the backend but for something the rows array is 0 length but the array is full how we can see in the second console.log?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the newRow() method as well!!

Comment: newRow():FormGroup{
        return this.fb.group({
            name: '',
            datatype: '',
            defaultValue: '',
            key: '',
            masked: '',
            size: '',
            pwx: ''
          });
    }

Comment: if it's possible to have a stackblitz or something, i don't know how we can help you, my first thought was maybe the formarray was disabled but i don't think it's because of this

Answer (score 0):

entity.rows is a `FormBuilder.array` and that is why you're getting an object which has an array - this is exactly what is returned when you do `console.log(b.value)`; In the demo code below, you can add more rows to this array and see the value that is printed on the screen.

relevant **TS**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  entityForm;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.entityForm = this.fb.group({
      // Searching ID
      search: this.fb.group({
        procedures: '',
        areas: '',
        entities: '',
        versions: '',
      }),
      // Entity
      entity: this.fb.group({
        // Id
        name: '',
        version: '',
        // Data Source
        cobolFileName: '',
        cobolUri: '',
        hostDbUri: '',
        hostDbTable: '',    // Format (schema.table)
        wsUri: '',
        // Historice
        historicizeStrategy: '',
        pwx: '',
        // Rows
        rows: this.fb.array([
          this.fb.control({ name: '', datatype: '', defaultValue: '', key: '', masked: '', size: '', pwx: '' })
        ])
      })
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.printStatus();
  }

  /*
    newRow(): FormGroup {
      return this.fb.control({ name: '', datatype: '', defaultValue: '', key: '', masked: '', size: '', pwx: '' });
    }
  */

  get rows() {
    return this.entityForm.get('entity.rows') as FormArray;
  }

  insertRow() {
    this.rows.push(
      this.fb.control({ name: '', datatype: '', defaultValue: '', key: '', masked: '', size: '', pwx: '' })
    );
    this.printStatus();
  }

  printStatus() {
    let a = this.entityForm.get('entity');
    let b = this.entityForm.get('entity.rows');
    console.log("entityForm.get('entity'):", a.value);
    console.log("entityForm.get('entity.rows'):", b.value);
  }

}
```

relevant **HTML**:

```
<button (click)='insertRow()'> insert a row </button> 
<br/>

{{ entityForm.value | json }}

<hr/>

<ul *ngFor='let item of entityForm?.value?.entity?.rows; let i = index'>
  <li>#{{i}} - [{{item.name}}] - [{{item.datatype}}]  - [{{item.key}}]  - [{{item.size}}] </li>
</ul>
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sgsy8t)

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem:
when I load the information that comes from the backend I clear the FormArray creating one new:

this.entityForm['controls'].entity['controls'].rows =this.fb.array([]);

For something I dont know this not work and create parallel array that depends how is accessed retrieve the data or the new empty array .
To solve, clear the array like this:

```
let rows2BeCleaned = (<FormArray>this.entityForm.get('entity.rows'));
while(rows2BeCleaned.length !=0){
    rows2BeCleaned.removeAt(0);
    }
```

If you use angular 8+ you can use the `this.entityForm.get('entity.rows').clear()` funtion.

Thanks to everyone that help me to review and catch the bug .